# React: Undefined after update state with array.

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to write a sudoku generator with React. Here's my action creator that will generate 2 dimensional array of my sudoku.

```
export const FETCH_FIELD = 'FETCH_FIELD';

export function complitedSudoku() {
  const field = [[0,1,3],[2,4,6]];

  return {
    type: FETCH_FIELD,
    payload: field
  }
}
```

Here's my container. He displays sudoku field. From the action creater my container takes values of cells and update state of container.

```
import { complitedSudoku } from '../actions/index';

class SudokuField extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { rowsAndCols: 0 };
    this.generateSudoku = this.generateSudoku.bind(this);
  }

  generateSudoku() {
    this.setState({rowsAndCols: this.props.complitedSudoku().payload})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1" width="50%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>{ this.state.rowsAndCols[0] }</th> // undefined
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <button onClick={ this.generateSudoku } type='submit' className='btn btn-secondary'>Generate Sudoku</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to specify concrete value of array (this.state.rowsAndCols[0][1]) I always get undefined value of array.

Comment: The first time, you didnt not set any initial state. So you might be getting rowsAndCols[0] as undefined.

Comment: Ahh, basics. Thank you.